# Redirect http calls inside iframe to https using nginx

Tags: nginx, proxy, https, http

I have an https website that needs to render an iframe of a external website that only works with http. The external http endpoints is all inside a url like: http://external-website.com/foobar

Browser don't allowed this (mixed content error. http inside https...), so I configured my https website nginx to create a reverse proxy on url /foobar to solve this issue.

Now I call the url: https://my-website/foobar, and that's render the iframe correctly.

The problem is: some buttons inside the iframe application calls hardcored http, and inside my website when I click those buttons, it calls http://my-website/foobar (the reverse proxy I setup but with http instead of https) and this give me mixed content error and the buttons dont work

I need some way to force all requests that go through /foobar to use https.

This is my current nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = "http") {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
    location /foobar/ {
        proxy_pass http://external-website.com/foobar/;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you must be able to modify the content of the pages, where the  [ngx_http_sub_module](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html) becomes handy.

> The `ngx_http_sub_module` module is a filter that modifies a response by replacing one specified string by another.
>
> This module is not built by default, it should be enabled with the `--with-http_sub_module` configuration parameter.

E.g., both Debian 12 & Ubuntu 22.04 has this module enabled on the packaged version of Nginx, and you could confirm that with `nginx -V`. (If not, you'd need to compile Nginx by yourself.)

After that it would be possible to replace the contents with, e.g.,

```
location /foobar/ {
    sub_filter 'http://example.net/' 'https://$host/foobar/';
    sub_filter_once off;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, especially the command nginx -v, I was able to confirm that nginx have http_sub_module, so I added this lines inside the location bracket: proxy_set_header Accept-Enconding ""; sub_filter_types *; sub_filter_once off; sub_filter 'http://' 'https://'; and that solve the problem

Comment: That wouldn't load the external content through the proxy, though? Is it available in HTTPS on the original site?

Comment: The external site only supports http. My reverse-proxy works with both http/https. I can load the iframe with the https url of my reverse-proxy, but the buttons inside the iframe calls my reverse-proxy with http url instead of https. With sub_filter now it the buttons inside the iframe call the url of my reverse-proxy with https